# Nginx alias still points to and loads from root directory

Tags: nginx

I have a django backend and react frontend.

I want to serve the react on `/` and use `/admin`, `/api` and `/auth` for Django. Here's what I have in my Nginx.

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name x.x.x.x;
    root /home/user/folder/frontend;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # for serving static
    location /static {
        alias /home/user/folder/backend/staticfiles;
    }

    # for serving react built files
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    # for everything django
    location ~^/(admin|api|auth) {
      include snippets/proxyinfo.conf;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

With the above, the expected behavior is

- `/` uses the default root folder, `/home/user/folder/frontend` and loads the built index files from react accordingly
- `/(admin|api|auth)` points to django
- `/static` loads static files saved in the `/home/user/folder/backend/staticfiles` folder.

So not sure why when I hit `example.com/static/myfile.css`, Nginx is going to `/home/user/folder/frontend/static/myfile.css`

I'd expect none of the above configuration says that's what it should do, so what magic is going on?

I thought this [answer was self explanatory enough](https://serverfault.com/a/684605/216502), yet Nginx keeps doing whatever it likes.

I'm using nginx/1.18.0 (if that matters)

Comment: Looks really weird. What happens if you'd add a trailing slash to both `location` and `alias` directives: `location /static/ { alias /home/user/folder/backend/staticfiles/; }` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `root` inside the `location /` directive too.

Like this:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;
    root /home/user/folder/backend/staticfiles;

    # for serving static
    location /static {
        alias /home/user/folder/backend/staticfiles;
    }

    # for serving react built files
    location / {
        root /home/user/folder/frontend;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # for everything django
    location ~^/(admin|api|auth) {
      include snippets/proxyinfo.conf;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

Also have a look at those QAs:

- [serve react frontend and php backend on same domain with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471249/serve-react-frontend-and-php-backend-on-same-domain-with-nginx)
- [Nginx -- static file serving confusion with root & alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)
- [Deploy both django and react on cloud using nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124421/deploy-both-django-and-react-on-cloud-using-nginx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the extra resources. Giving it a try to see how it goes

Comment: I get this error `"/home/user/folder/backend/staticfiles/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory)` using your answer

Comment: Where do you get the error? When restarting nginx or when accessing an url? Which url?

Comment: When accessing the `/` url. And the `/admin` and others show up as not found

Answer (score 0):

from ngix documentation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html), it seems you are missing a `/` at the end of your paths. this trailing `/` can cause a lot of pain in many languages to be the root cause of many errors.

please give it a try like this:

```
# for serving static
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/user/folder/backend/staticfiles/;
    }
```